# jira - 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url

Tags: slack-api, jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

I'm creating a Slack bot to connect to Jira. The whole thing works on my local machine, however, when I deploy the server on a VM (Azure), it gives me this error. Any thoughts?
Error:

```
401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://***.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?startAt=0&fields=%2Aall&jql=project%3Dtest
2022-11-09 17:31:40,851 - ERROR - slack_bolt.App - Failed to run listener function (error: Object of type HTTPError is not JSON serializable)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_bolt/listener/thread_runner.py", line 120, in run_ack_function_asynchronously
    listener.run_ack_function(request=request, response=response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_bolt/listener/custom_listener.py", line 50, in run_ack_function
    return self.ack_function(
  File "/home/ubuntu/flask/src/helpers/slack_controller.py", line 87, in handle_jira_action
    sj_view_one(slack_app, body)
  File "/home/ubuntu/flask/src/helpers/slack_jira_services.py", line 41, in sj_view_one
    slack_app.client.views_open(trigger_id=body['trigger_id'], view={
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/client.py", line 4452, in views_open
    return self.api_call("views.open", json=kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 156, in api_call
    return self._sync_send(api_url=api_url, req_args=req_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 187, in _sync_send
    return self._urllib_api_call(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 294, in _urllib_api_call
    response = self._perform_urllib_http_request(url=url, args=request_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 339, in _perform_urllib_http_request
    body = json.dumps(args["json"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type HTTPError is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, I found the answer. There are two problems here:

First, Unauthorized.
This is a problem I have with Atlassian API. (Have a ticket opened for it, however, they couldn't help me with it yet).

Second, TypeError.
For fixing this, one way is to map the exception error to a string. For example:

```
try:
    something()
exception Exception as error:
    logger.error(str(error))
    return str(error)
```

instead of returning the error, I sent str(error).